# I can't connect to my dropwizard application remotely

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I am able to succesfully use my dropwizard application when accessing with localhosts,  but it doesnt work when I access with a different machine.  Is there something you need to do make your web application respond to hosts besides localhosts?

I know with flask you must run with the `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`  is there a setting in the config file which controls this.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect from the same network you´ll probably have an windows firewall issue (if you run on windows) or any other firewall depending on the OS.
You´ll have to allow inbound connections for the specific application on or port 80/443 TCP.

If you´re trying to connect from another network then it probably still is the above but you also have to setup port-forwarding to the machine running your application.
If it´s HTTP, probably port 80. If HTTPS then probably 443, for any other protocol you have to find out the correct port.

Since it´s dropwizard it´s probably HTTP/HTTPS, depending if it has to be secure (definatly recommended for REST APIs)

Comment: It's from a macOS,  I checked and I dont think I have a firewall up.

```bash-3.2# sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --getglobalstate
Firewall is disabled. (State = 0)
bash-3.2# 
```

I'm not sure about the port forwarding.  Suppose,  I went <IP_ADDRESS>:8080/<path>  would that not go to the right port?

Also thanks for the help,  I've been trying to debug this for hours now

Comment: Son of a gun,  I am now finding out you were correct.  I was experience a combination of firewall and networking issues.  Thanks :)  I've been able to resolve this now

Comment: Firewalls usually are a pain in the a** but I guess there´s a reason why those things exist (security and stuff). 
Great to hear that it now works for you